# Vuex mutations without referencing state directly?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am learning Vuex and my understanding so far has been that mutations should be simple functions that update the state directly using something like `state.property = value` or `state.object = {payload}`, e.g.:

```
SET_USER_DATA (state, userData) {
  state.user = userData    
}
```

I am working through a course from Vue Mastery that contains mutations that look like the code below which does not reference the `state` object within the body of the mutation at all:

```
CREATE_TASK(state, { tasks, name }) {
  tasks.push({ name, id: generateId(), description: "" });
},
UPDATE_TASK(state, { task, field, value }) {
   Vue.set(task, field, value);
},
```

`CREATE_TASK` creates a new empty task and adds it to the tasks array using `tasks.push()`, but shouldn't a reference to the state object be required to update the `state`? E.g. `state.tasks.push()`? How does simply pushing an item onto a bare array commit the change to the state?

In the second example, they use `Vue.set()` to update the value of a specific field within a task (e.g. `name`, `description`), but again, there is no reference to the state object here.

The best I can figure is that they relying on Vue's native reactivity to automatically update the state when calling `Vue.set()` or `Array.push()`. But if that is the case, wouldn't any usage of `Vue.set()` or `Array.push()` inside of a component also immediately update the state (violating the rule that state changes should only be handled within a mutation?

Comment: the code seems wrong to me. ideally mutations should update the state object.

Comment: It's hard to tell without full context, but I'm guessing the `tasks` value that would be passed in the payload of `CREATE_TASK` would be a reference to an array that is already stored in the state? For example, maybe it is a reference to `state.tasks`? Perhaps it was written this way so that you could have more than one array of tasks in the state. For example you could have `state.tasks_lists` which contain an array of task lists and then you could add tasks to one of them using `CREATE_TASK`? For example with `store.commit('CREATE_TASK', {'tasks': state.tasks_lists[0], 'name': 'test'})`.

Comment: Delena Malan, yes i think you exactly right. The tasks array is a passed to the component as a computed property via ...mapState(). The tasks array that gets passed back to the commit function is a subset (column) of the full task list. So I guess it makes sense where the state is essentially being passed into the mutation as part of the payload that we don't need to reference the state again.

Comment: The example will work correctly, if `tasks` is actually `state.tasks` and `task` is one of them (in `update` mutation). `Vue.set()` does update correctly and fires the internal observers Vue reactivity relies on. If you ran this code outside of a mutation, Vue would complain about it: you're mutating state contents outside of a mutation. The only *"wrong"* part about using it this way is that this is featured on a website aimed at teaching Vue to newcomers and its confusing.

Comment: The proper way would be to pass an `id`, find the object to be mutated in state, by id, and update it (for `update` method). And for `add` method, you don't actually need `tasks` at all, one can just push to `state.tasks`.